# if the sum of the distances of a point from two

Tags: geometry

If the sum of the distances of a point from two perpendicular lines in a plane is 1, then its locus is

(A) square

(B) a circle

(C) straight line

(D) two intersecting lines

I am currently studying high school geometry and have almost completed my lesson on straight lines. I am unable to find the answer of this question even after trying all the ways I knew of. Please help.

Comment: Hint: assume the two lines are the $x$ and $y$ axes. The distance of a point $(x, y)$ to the $y$ axis is $|x|$. The distance from $(x, y)$ to the $x$ axis is $|y|$.

Comment: I think I got it. mod x + mod y=1 will be the required equation and it frms a square. Am i right?

Comment: Good! If you want, write your solution in an answer to your own question.

Comment: Ok. I will try. BTW thanks for help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @dantopa I have edited the question but it is still on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed assume that the two lines are the coordinate axis, as you can translate/rotate them without changing the distance.

Now the sum of distances can be written as

$$|x|+|y|=1=L_1(x,y;0,0)$$

where $L_p$ denotes the [Minkowski distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance) of order $p$.

With $p=1$, you get a square diamond. With $p=2$, a circle, and with $p=\infty$, a straight square.

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that the perpendicular lines are X and Y axis.

So the distance of the point from x axis will be $\left|y\right|$ and from Y axis will be $\left|y\right|$.

So the required equation will be $\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|=1$.

And that is a square!